# CSS grid - start all coumns from start with auto height on each

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to have columns in which X amount of items can be placed and i want them to start from position 0 and stack up with auto height:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items:start;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1{grid-column-start:1; grid-column-end:1; grid-auto-rows: auto;}
.item-2{grid-column-start:1; grid-column-end:1; grid-auto-rows: auto;}
.item-3{grid-column-start:2; grid-column-end:2; grid-auto-rows: auto;}
.item-4{grid-column-start:3; grid-column-end:3; grid-auto-rows: auto;}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-1">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-3">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item item-4">4</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w63vkrLj/)

This is a drawing what i want to achieve:
[Wanted result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpEZZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using flex box you can do something like this :

```css
.style {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid-item {
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.item-spe {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="item style"></div>
    <div class="item style"></div>
    <div class="item style"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item style"></div>
  <div class="grid-item style item-spe"></div>
  <div class="grid-item style"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly i dont have the option to put them into groups like that, its a dinamically generated list (ul li), and the user want to select specific column by adding a css class

Comment: Each element with border on you image exemple represent an element. If you do not have these element you can't make it. If you can't make it into groups like I did you can still manage it. But if you can't have more div you won't be able to do it.